# Items clickable but invisible on screen: downloaded via AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, loader

I'm storing a list of the most frequented transit lines in a Content Provider and a RecyclerView Adapter to be available in online and offline viewing. They are downloaded into an activity via AsyncTaskLoader. They are accessible from the menu option in the activity below. I debugged and it shows that items are being added to the Content Provider in another activity. Then, when I click on "most frequented" in the menu option, the screen is blank but the items are clickable(both on and offline). I've tried to debug but it's not showing any errors.

I found a similar thread:
[RecyclerView items are clickable but invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082658/recyclerview-items-are-clickable-but-invisible)

In my case, all the fonts and colors are correct. I know that the Loader is deprecated as of sdk 28. However, it's not even working in 27. Thank you in advance.

Activity where the data is added to the Content Provider:

```
public class StationListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StationsAdapter.StationsAdapterOnClickHandler, TubeStationAsyncTaskInterface,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    //Tag for the log messages
    private static final String TAG = StationListActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview_station)
    RecyclerView mStationRecyclerView;

    private StationsAdapter stationsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Stations> stationsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String KEY_STATIONS_LIST = "stations_list";
    private static final String KEY_LINE_NAME = "line_name";
    Lines lines;
    public String lineId;
    private Context context;
    private TextView lineNameStation;
    private String lineNameToString;

    @BindView(R.id.favorites_button)
    Button favoritesButton;

    /**
     * Identifier for the favorites data loader
     */
    private static final int FAVORITES_LOADER = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_station_list);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Bind the views
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        stationsAdapter = new StationsAdapter(this, stationsArrayList, context);
        mStationRecyclerView.setAdapter(stationsAdapter);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mStationLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mStationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStationLayoutManager);

        lineNameStation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.line_name_station);

        //add to favorites
        favoritesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_ID, lines.getLineId());
                values.put(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_NAME, lines.getLineName());
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

                if (uri != null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(StationListActivity.this, R.string.favorites_added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favoritesButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        });

        /*
         *  Starting the asyncTask so that stations load when the activity opens.
         */

            if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null)
            {
                if (savedInstanceState == null)
                {
                lines = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Lines");
                lineId = lines.getLineId();

                TubeStationAsyncTask myStationTask = new TubeStationAsyncTask(this);
                myStationTask.execute(lineId);

                lineNameStation.setText(lines.getLineName());

            } else
                {
                stationsArrayList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_STATIONS_LIST);
                stationsAdapter.setStationsList(stationsArrayList);

            }
        }
        // Kick off the loader
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(FAVORITES_LOADER, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void returnStationData(ArrayList<Stations> simpleJsonStationData) {
        if (null != simpleJsonStationData) {
            stationsAdapter = new StationsAdapter(this, simpleJsonStationData, StationListActivity.this);
            stationsArrayList = simpleJsonStationData;
            mStationRecyclerView.setAdapter(stationsAdapter);
            stationsAdapter.setStationsList(stationsArrayList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(Stations stations) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StationListActivity.this, StationScheduleActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Stations", stations);
        intent.putExtra("Lines", lines);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle bundle)
    {
        String[] projection = {TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry._ID, TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_ID,};
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{lineId};

        switch (loaderId)
        {
            case FAVORITES_LOADER:
                return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
                        TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
                        projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                        TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_ID + "=?",
                        selectionArgs,
                        null);                  // Default sort order

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Loader Not Implemented: " + loaderId);
        }
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor)
    {
        if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0))
        {
            //"Add to Favorites" button is disabled in the StationList Activity when the user clicks on a line stored in Favorites
            favoritesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader)
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_STATIONS_LIST, stationsArrayList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Activity with the menu option:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LinesAdapter.LinesAdapterOnClickHandler, TubeLineAsyncTaskInterface,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    // Tag for logging
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview_main)
    RecyclerView mLineRecyclerView;
    private LinesAdapter linesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Lines> linesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private static final String KEY_LINES_LIST = "lines_list";
    CoordinatorLayout mCoordinatorLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.pb_loading_indicator)
    ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

    private AdView adView;
    private FavoritesAdapter favoritesAdapter;
    private static final int FAVORITES_LOADER_ID = 0;
    private int mPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Bind the views
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        mCoordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        favoritesAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(this, context);
        linesAdapter = new LinesAdapter(this, linesArrayList, context);
        mLineRecyclerView.setAdapter(linesAdapter);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLineLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mLineRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLineLayoutManager);


        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                if (viewHolder instanceof LinesAdapter.LinesAdapterViewHolder) return 0;
                return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            }

            // Called when a user swipes left or right on a ViewHolder
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                // Here is where you'll implement swipe to delete

                //Construct the URI for the item to delete
                //[Hint] Use getTag (from the adapter code) to get the id of the swiped item
                // Retrieve the id of the task to delete
                int id = (int) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();

                // Build appropriate uri with String row id appended
                String stringId = Integer.toString(id);
                Uri uri = TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.CONTENT_URI;
                uri = uri.buildUpon().appendPath(stringId).build();

                // TODO (2) Delete a single row of data using a ContentResolver
                int rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                Log.v("CatalogActivity", rowsDeleted + " rows deleted from the movie database");
                // TODO (3) Restart the loader to re-query for all tasks after a deletion
                getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(FAVORITES_LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(mLineRecyclerView);

        /*
         *  Starting the asyncTask so that lines load upon launching the app.
         */
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            if (isNetworkStatusAvailable(this))
            {
                TubeLineAsyncTask myLineTask = new TubeLineAsyncTask(this);
                myLineTask.execute(NetworkUtils.buildLineUrl());
            } else {
                Snackbar
                        .make(mCoordinatorLayout, "Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("Retry", new MyClickListener())
                        .show();
            }
        } else {

            linesArrayList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_LINES_LIST);
            linesAdapter.setLinesList(linesArrayList);
        }
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(FAVORITES_LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);
       mLineRecyclerView.setAdapter(favoritesAdapter);
    }

    public class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Run the AsyncTask in response to the click
            TubeLineAsyncTask myLineTask = new TubeLineAsyncTask(MainActivity.this);
            myLineTask.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void returnLineData(ArrayList<Lines> simpleJsonLineData) {
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (null != simpleJsonLineData) {
            linesAdapter = new LinesAdapter(this, simpleJsonLineData, MainActivity.this);
            linesArrayList = simpleJsonLineData;
            mLineRecyclerView.setAdapter(linesAdapter);
            linesAdapter.setLinesList(linesArrayList);
        } else {
            showErrorMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(Lines lines) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StationListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Lines", lines);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //Display if there is no internet connection
    public void showErrorMessage() {
        Snackbar
                .make(mCoordinatorLayout, "Please check your internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Retry", new MyClickListener())
                .show();
        mLineRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs)
    {

        return new AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>(this)
        {

            // Initialize a Cursor, this will hold all the task data
            Cursor mFavoritesData = null;

            // onStartLoading() is called when a loader first starts loading data
            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading()
            {
                if (mFavoritesData != null)
                {
                    // Delivers any previously loaded data immediately
                    deliverResult(mFavoritesData);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Force a new load
                    forceLoad();
                }
            }

            // loadInBackground() performs asynchronous loading of data
            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground()
            {
                // Will implement to load data

                // Query and load all task data in the background; sort by priority
                // [Hint] use a try/catch block to catch any errors in loading data

                try
                {
                    return getContentResolver().query(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                             TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_ID);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to asynchronously load data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            // deliverResult sends the result of the load, a Cursor, to the registered listener
            public void deliverResult(Cursor data)
            {
                mFavoritesData = data;
                super.deliverResult(data);
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Called when a previously created loader has finished its load.
     *
     * @param loader The Loader that has finished.
     * @param data   The data generated by the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
        favoritesAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        if (mPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) mPosition = 0;
        mLineRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition);

    }

    /**
     * Called when a previously created loader is being reset, and thus
     * making its data unavailable.
     * onLoaderReset removes any references this activity had to the loader's data.
     *
     * @param loader The Loader that is being reset.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        favoritesAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /* Use AppCompatActivity's method getMenuInflater to get a handle on the menu inflater */
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        /* Use the inflater's inflate method to inflate our menu layout to this menu */
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        /* Return true so that the menu is displayed in the Toolbar */
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        TubeLineAsyncTask myLineTask = new TubeLineAsyncTask(this);

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.most_frequented_favorites:

                getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(FAVORITES_LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);
                favoritesAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(this, MainActivity.this);
                mLineRecyclerView.setAdapter(favoritesAdapter);
                return true;

            case R.id.line_list:
                myLineTask.execute();
                return true;

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }}

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_LINES_LIST, linesArrayList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
public class FavoritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesAdapter.FavoritesAdapterViewHolder>
{
    private static final String TAG = FavoritesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private LinesAdapter.LinesAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    public FavoritesAdapter(LinesAdapter.LinesAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler, Context context)
    {
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
        this.context = context;
    }
    public class FavoritesAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @BindView(R.id.line_name)
        TextView lineName;

        public FavoritesAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(getAdapterPosition());

            String lineName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_NAME));
            String lineId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_ID));

            Lines line = new Lines(lineName, lineId);

            mClickHandler.onClick(line);
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(FavoritesAdapter.FavoritesAdapterViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            // get to the right location in the cursor
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            // Determine the values of the wanted data
            int lineIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_ID);

            final int id = cursor.getInt(lineIdIndex);

            holder.itemView.setTag(id);

        }

        @Override
        public FavoritesAdapter.FavoritesAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)
        {
            Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
            int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.line_list_item;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
            View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
            return new FavoritesAdapter.FavoritesAdapterViewHolder(view);
        }

        public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c)
        {
            // check if this cursor is the same as the previous cursor (mCursor)
            if (cursor == c)
            {
                return null; // bc nothing has changed
            }

            Cursor temp = cursor;
            this.cursor = c; // new cursor value assigned

            //check if this is a valid cursor, then update the cursor
            if (c != null)
            {
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return temp;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            if (null == cursor)
                return 0;
            return cursor.getCount();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @notTdar stationsAdapter loads a list of stations. There are no issues there. I'm passing data back to the Main Activity from where I got the parcelable:  lines = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Lines");

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder()`, you're not setting any text on the `ViewHolder`'s `TextView`.

Comment: @MikeM.Solved! Thank you for pointing that out. I deleted the name because for some reason I thought that "id" was enough in the ViewHolder since it corresponds to the name. Had to add this.  int lineNameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TubeLineContract.TubeLineEntry.COLUMN_LINES_NAME);

            String stationName = cursor.getString(lineNameColumnIndex);  holder.lineName.setText(stationName);